# can't figure out this null point exception error

Tags: android

making a coin flip option within an app.  Here's the part that's killing me:

```
public ImageView tails;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    .....

}
```

in the menu is where the issue happens:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {


case R.id.coin_flip:

                final Context cointext = this;
                final Dialog flip = new Dialog(cointext);
                flip.setContentView(R.layout.coin);

                flip.setTitle("Coin Flip");
                flip.setCancelable(true);

                n = 99;
                n = (generator.nextInt(n)) + 1;
                tails.findViewById(R.id.tails).setVisibility(1);

                if (n % 2 == 0) {
                    tails.findViewById(R.id.tails).setVisibility(0);
                }else {
                    tails.findViewById(R.id.tails).setVisibility(1);
                }

                Button flipBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.flipBtn);
                flipBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (n % 2 == 0) {
                            tails.findViewById(R.id.tails).setVisibility(0);
                        }else {
                            tails.findViewById(R.id.tails).setVisibility(1);
                        }
                    }
                });

                flip.show();
}
}
```

I keep getting a NullPointerException on:

```
tails.findViewById(R.id.tails).setVisibility(1);
```

any ideas how to fix this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you set the variable `tails`? Could you add the code here.

Comment: Check this [Get NullPointer Exeption](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/why-nullpointerexception-occures-in.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tails isn't being initialized.

You should say

```
tails = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.tails);
tails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: I think my brain is fried... that helped, but now I'm getting a NullPointerException on flipBtn.setOnClickListener...